# Why can't I call methods on a for-yield expression?

Tags: scala

Say I have some Scala code like this:

```
// Outputs 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100
println( squares)

def squares = {
    val s = for ( count <- 1 to 10 )
                yield { count * count }
    s.mkString(", ");
}
```

Why do I have to use the temporary val s?  I tried this:

```
def squares = for ( count <- 1 to 10 )
                  yield { count * count }.mkString(", ")
```

That fails to compile with this error message:

```
error: value mkString is not a member of Int
   def squares = for ( count <- 1 to 10 ) yield { count * count }.mkString(", ")
```

Shouldn't `mkString` be called on the collection returned by the `for` loop?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a missing parenthesis. You want to call the `mkString` method on the result of the `for`-expression. Without the extra parenthesis the compiler thinks you wanted to call the `mkString`-method on `{count * cout}` which is an `Int`.

```
scala> def squares = (for ( count <- 1 to 10 ) yield { count * count }).mkString(", ")
squares: String

scala> squares
res2: String = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100
```

Anyway I suggest you to should use the `map` method instead:

```
scala> 1 to 10 map { x => x*x } mkString(", ")
res0: String = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100
```

Comment: His for comprehension is just syntactic sugar for the exact same map method that you provided. What you want to use is just a matter of taste, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Just put parentheses around the for loop and it works:

```
scala> (for (count <- 1 to 10) yield { count * count }).mkString(", ")
```

`res0: String = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100`

Answer (score 3):

When you call `mkString` as you have in your second example, it's not being called on the collection but on each individual integer being returned, hence the error message: `mkString is not a member of Int`.
If you want to call methods on the `for..yield` expression itself, you'll need to parenthesize it:

```
def squares = (for (count <- 1 to 10) yield { count * count }).mkString(", ")
```